# Triggering Click event when page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have the following script (in php) to trigger the `button` once the page is loaded.

However, I am getting an error.

```
<button type="submit" id="the_button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>

<script>// <![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#the_button").trigger('click');
});

// ]]></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

So, I guess code itself is correct but it is not doing what I want to achieve.

Here is the scenario.

I have a button which when clicked, it triggers a drop down option.
So, I am trying to automatically trigger this button to be clicked as soon as page is loaded so the follow up action is already triggered without user inputs.

Would the code that I have achieve that purpose?

EDIT 2:

I changed my code to the following and I am not getting an error but still it is not working or is not doing anything. I am thinking to delay the `click` event by 1 second. How do I delay it? Thanks

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){   
jQuery("#the_button").trigger('click');    
return false;       });     
}
```

Comment: That should work. What makes you think it's wrong? Note that trigger simply executes the on click events. It won't actually click the button.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I edited my question. But I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Have you included jQuery source in the page?

Comment: Maybe change `$(document).ready(` to `$(window).load(`

Comment: Sounds like you are not loading jQuery before you are calling the page load function

Comment: I changed my code (Edit 2) to include jQuery. Although I am not getting any error anymore, I am still not getting any action. What do you guys think ? Should I delay the `click` event ?

Comment: Try insert "alert" before the trigger. If the alert is not seen, jquery is not loaded. If it is, you can try trigger with "setTimeout" js function

Comment: Is the button within a form? What is supposed to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: Please add the code of the click-handler to your question. A working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even better

Comment: @ZivWeissman, looks like jQuery is running for sure. I will try to use the `setTimeout`. @jbowman, when this button is clicked, then it brings down an inquiry form where user can contact me with. However right now, it takes half second to load the form. Thus, I am trying to load this form the moment the page is ready, then hide the form in a `dropdown` like menu, so that when the user clicks `Contact me`, then there is no delay in loading the form as the form is already loaded the moment page was loaded.

Comment: AFAIK, the `click` event does not automatically raise `submit` event that is needed to submit form..